# Azure DevOps- Postman Installation

Tags: azure-devops, postman

I have tried to install Postman.exe file using DevOps pipeline and I create a release the release pipeline killed my node server process in cleanup phase.

Finalize Job:
2023-08-21T09:38:25.4699532Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2023-08-21T09:38:25.4730204Z Cleaning up task key
2023-08-21T09:38:25.4732859Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job

I believe it's installing and in last step - cleanup the process. Can Someone help me how to stop from cleaning up the process?

I have tried to set variable to "Process.clean= false." still no luck.

Appreciate your help!

Code used is below

$installerPath = "D:\ins\Postman.exe"

Start-Process -FilePath $installerPath -ArgumentList  '/S'

I have tried to set variable to "Process.clean= false." still no luck